# Admob in Android problem

Tags: android, admob

I am currently developing an application and decided to try Admob ads.

Unfortunately, after following Admob's guide (pretty simple one, good job on that) I get no ad, whether I run it on the emulator or on my phone (HTC Desire). The weird part is that the ad has shown a couple of times (I really mean just a couple of times), in hundreds of tries. And checking my account on Admob I see that there are 6000 requests from this app.

I started a new application, from a blank slate, with no changes.

Any clues?

This is what I have done so far:

- Added Admob's library JAR.
- Added these in my manifest (with a proper ID):

  ```
  meta-data android:value="axxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" /  
  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /
  ```
- Created a `attrs.xml` file in `res/values` with this content:

  ```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
  resources>  
  declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">  
  attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />  
  attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />  
  attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />  
  attr name="keywords" format="string" />  
  attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />  
  /declare-styleable>  
  /resources>
  ```
- Added the following to my layout (`RelativeLayout`):

  - below RelativeLayout line, with the correct application name instead of xxxx:

    ```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.me.xxxx"
    ```

    and:

    ```
    com.admob.android.ads.AdView  
    android:id="@+id/ad"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
    app:backgroundColor="#000000"  
    app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"  
    app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"  
    />
    ```
- As the above did not work I tried the following, but also without success:

  ```
  AdView example_adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
  example_adview.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
  example_adview.requestFreshAd();
  ```

Comment: This question is using attrs.xml, which likely means it's using Admob 4.0.4 or older. 4.1.0 has some changes described in [this google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5) (look for Tim's post).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] {                 
        AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR 
});
```

to the Activity-class that is to show the ad?

If you're debugging using your phone you also need to add the ID of your phone to the array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Using test mode I got ads to show successfully, both on emulator and device.

My question is whether the real ads will show up, when I take these test lines out, in my final application for other people? 

I get the feeling that they only show once every 100.
The message I get in logcat is "No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available". Is this normal?